# How to configure secure login module in drupal?

Tags: php

How to configure secure login module in drupal?

If you know how to configure this module in drupal, or please tell me tutorials site & tutorials video about this.

Answer (score 0):

I found on drupal website

> Secure Login module enables the user
>   login and other forms to be submitted
>   securely via HTTPS, thus preventing
>   passwords and other private user data
>   from being transmitted in clear text.
>   For Drupal 7, Secure Login module also
>   enforces secure authenticated session
>   cookies, thus preventing session
>   sidejacking. For previous versions of
>   Drupal, PHP's session.cookie_secure
>   flag must be enabled on the HTTPS site
>   to enforce secure authenticated
>   sessions.
>
> http://drupal.org/project/securelogin